# Is there any way to listen smart contract events from nodejs-expressjs server?

Tags: solidity, events, nodejs, express

I am developing a smart contract project and I need to listen events on my expressjs-server. Is it possible to listen events from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Graph to subscribe to event from your contract from your expressjs-server https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/the-graph-fixing-web3-data-querying/#gatsby-focus-wrapper as an alternative you can use Ethers.JS https://docs.ethers.io/v5/concepts/events/

Comment: The Graph doesn't help to actively listen to events because it does not trigger any update to the node-express server. It only extracts data from the blockchain, processing it and storing it so that it can be easily queried via GraphQL.

Answer (score 0):

use web3.js events listener emitted by smart contract
Official docs link -

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth-contract.html#events